# PHP Submit button change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I got this code:

```
<?php
// ----------------------------------------- 
//  The Web Help .com
// ----------------------------------------- 
// remember to replace your@email.com with your own email address lower in this code.

// load the variables form address bar
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$message = $_REQUEST["message"];
$from = $_REQUEST["from"];
$verif_box = $_REQUEST["verif_box"];

// remove the backslashes that normally appears when entering " or '
$name = stripslashes($name); 
$message = stripslashes($message); 
$from = stripslashes($from); 

// check to see if verificaton code was correct
if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
    // if verification code was correct send the message and show this page
    $message = "Name: ".$name."\n".$message;
    $message = "From: ".$from."\n".$message;
    mail("myMail@gmail.com", 'MSG from site', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n".$message, "From: $from");
    // delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
    setcookie('tntcon','');
} else {
    // if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error
    header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?&from=$from&message=$message&wrong_code=true");
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>PHP Contact Form Redirect</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is:

1. After I click the submit button of this form I want to stay on the same page
2. After the message is sent properly I want the button to change the text from "Send" to "MSG Sent" (and maybe change the button color to green)

How am I supposed to do these things?

Any chance of linking to a source I can learn how to code this?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look at [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to do this. Below is a starting point.

```
var dataString = $("#contactform").serialize();

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "../public/txtmailer-v3.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
        success: function(html){
        //insert html and css edits here
       }, error: function(html){
           alert("Error sending email!");
       }
     }
});
```

[A tutorial is here.](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

These two links will be useful.

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 0):

1. To stay on the same page after submit you just fill in `action=""` into the form tags or you can leave action out completely.
2. To change the button text you can use javascript `document.getElementById("buttonId").value= "MSG";`